# Parsing a Nested JSON using python3 - getting KeyError, Could you please guide?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am getting below sample data through get api call in json format. trying to parse the 'members' data form json but getting KeyError.

**Sample data:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "searchResult": [
      {
        "teamName": "abc comp",
        "startDate": "20190901",
        "status": "Open",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5nf00000000OPqAAM",
        "asOfDate": "20190927",
        "runDateTime": "20190927T210031+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "abc Reporting",
        "startDate": "20181129",
        "status": "Open",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5n0R0000002hqLQAQ",
        "asOfDate": "20190919",
        "runDateTime": "20190919T184824+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "abc 766",
        "startDate": "20190702",
        "status": "Open",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5n0R0000003InpQAE",
        "asOfDate": "20190919",
        "runDateTime": "20190919T184824+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "abc comp 1",
        "closeDate": "20190127",
        "startDate": "20190125",
        "status": "Closed",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5n0R000000DNoAQAW",
        "members": [
          {
            "memberName": "TM0000005872",
            "memberSFId": "a5m0R000000DDIYQA4",
            "active": false,
            "contactName": "intcontact 1",
            "coreTeamMember": "Yes",
            "endDate": "20190127",
            "personId": 0,
            "hybridRoleFlag": false,
            "launchMember": false,
            "role": "abc Analyst",
            "startDate": "20190125",
            "teamLeader": "No"
          }
        ],
        "asOfDate": "20190919",
        "runDateTime": "20190919T184824+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "abc comp D",
        "startDate": "20191022",
        "status": "Open",
        "teamCode": "TC100004",
        "teamSFId": "a5nf00000004U5gAAE",
        "asOfDate": "20191104",
        "runDateTime": "20191104T163644+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "abc comp 766",
        "startDate": "20190703",
        "status": "Open",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5n0R0000003JRpQAM",
        "members": [
          {
            "memberName": "TM0000006456",
            "memberSFId": "a5m0R0000000UYvQAM",
            "active": true,
            "contactName": "Leonel",
            "coreTeamMember": "Yes",
            "personId": 31429,
            "hybridRoleFlag": false,
            "launchMember": false,
            "primaryTeamAssociation": "No",
            "role": "TransporManager",
            "startDate": "20190703",
            "teamLeader": "No",
            "samAccountName": "LeoM"
          }
        ],
        "asOfDate": "20190919",
        "runDateTime": "20190919T184824+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "Test abc Service",
        "startDate": "20191119",
        "distributionList": "Angela Li",
        "status": "Open",
        "teamCode": "TC100014",
        "teamDesc": "testing",
        "teamSFId": "a5nf00000004UZvAAM",
        "asOfDate": "20191119",
        "runDateTime": "20191119T100022+0000"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "MLB abc comp Team 1",
        "startDate": "20181101",
        "status": "Open",
        "category": "abc Service",
        "domain": "abc comp",
        "teamSFId": "a5n0R0000004TC3QAM",
        "asOfDate": "20190919",
        "runDateTime": "20190919T184824+0000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "success",
  "code": "0",
  "errorMsg": null,
  "httpResponseCode": 200
}
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json

targeturl = 'https://xyz.abc.com' 
response = requests.get(targeturl, auth=('username', 'password'))
content = response.content.decode('utf-8') 
json_data = json.loads(content) 

team = json_data['data']['searchResult']
for team_data in team:
    print(team_data) #Able to parse team data
member = team_data['members'] # -> getting error while parsing member data
```

> quote
>   Error:
>   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 member = team_data['members']

KeyError: 'members'

> quote

Comment: Not every object inside `searchResults` (which your code bound to `team_data`) has the `members` key - try using `team_data.get('members')` instead to avoid the `KeyError`, but at the expense of having `None` be bound to `members`.

Comment: Perhaps there is no Key 'members' in team_data.

Comment: yeah some team may not have members associated with , i need to extract member data only for the team it exist

Comment: could you please help , still facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if member field id present in the given team_data variable.
It can be done by using

```
if "members" in team_data.keys()
    member=team_data["members"]
```

As there are members in some team_data but not present in some

Comment: Thanks for the insight.   team_data.keys() gives - >  dict_keys(['teamName', 'startDate', 'status', 'category', 'domain', 'teamSFId', 'asOfDate', 'runDateTime']) . Do i need to use any loop for this check?

Comment: could you please help , still facing the issue.

Comment: In some of team_data there is no 'members' field so you can access it.
Due to this above condition check for members key is team_data variable using `"members" in team_data.keys()` as it return true then only it can parse the given team_data members field